# Where can I find data for the masses/component velocities of galaxies in the Local Group?

Tags: astronomy, resource-recommendations, simulations, galaxies, software

I am trying to run an N body simulation to see how galaxies in the Local Group gravitationally interact for my thesis, but I can't find any data for the masses of the galaxies in the Local Group, or the x,y,z components of their velocities (I can only find their redshifts). I have used the NED database to calculate their positions but this database doesn't seem to help with what I'm asking for above.

Does anyone know of a particular database or literature which would provide any of these details?

Comment: IMHO, [Astronomy.SE](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) is a better choice for this particular question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find data for the masses/component velocities for galaxies in the Local Group?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/242531/where-can-i-find-data-for-the-masses-component-velocities-for-galaxies-in-the-lo)

Comment: Please do not crosspost questions.

Comment: [Cross-posted to astronomy.](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14096/where-can-i-find-data-for-the-masses-component-velocities-for-galaxies-in-the-lo) Please just post to one site or the other.

Comment: Also, you already have one velocity component from redshift. The other two, however, are not nearly as easy to ascertain as you might think. The transverse motion of even the *nearest* galaxy was only [measured a few years ago](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2012ApJ...753....7S), and it took one of the best telescopes ever built, together with years of patience, to do that.

Comment: @levitopher: I believe spec. ref. tag does not apply; please read its tag wiki.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I have seen somewhere that it is a lot simpler to assign random velocities to the galaxies within a range of their radial velocities, are their radial velocities easier to find?